# XPath syntax: How to get the child div information based on parent div

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

The result from my scrapy project looks like this:

```
<div class="news_li">...</div>
<div class="news_li">...</div>
<div class="news_li">...</div>
...
<div class="news_li">...</div>
```

And each "news_li" class looks like this:

```
 <div class="news_li">
    <div class="a">
        <a href="aaa">
            <div class="a1"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <a href="xxx">
        <div class="b">
            <div class="b1"></div>
            <div class="b2"></div>
            <div class="b3"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract information one at a time in the scrapy shell by the following command:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='news_li']")[0].xpath("//div[@class='a1']").extract()
response.xpath("//div[@class='news_li  ']/descendant::div[@class='a1']").extract()
```

But these commands returns me with all the "a1" class from all other "news_li" class

I have 2 quesitons:

1. How do I get the child div information one at a time.
2. How do I get the `<a href="aaa"> </a> and <a href="xxx"> </a>` separately? (The difference is the first one is wrap in a parent div and the second one is by itself.)

Many Many thanks in advance.

Edit: To be specific, how can i extract the information depends on the parent /root node? I look up [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) and I tried with 'descendant', but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below.

```
# first link
response.xpath("(//div[@class='news_li']//a)[1]").extract()
# second link
response.xpath("(//div[@class='news_li']//a)[2]").extract()
```

**Edit 1:**

```
 # change the X value in the below xpath to get the first link
//div[@class='news_li'][X]/descendant::div[@class='a1']/parent::a

 # change the X value in the below xpath to get the second link (direct
 # link) based on the child div
 //div[@class='news_li'][X]/descendant::a[div[@class='b']]
```

Comment: I am not sure if its a good idea to get it by id. Is there a way to get it depends on the parent node?  [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) this is what i am lookfing for but I am having a hard time to understand it.

Comment: @SamMinWong If by "get it by id" you mean identifying elements by relative position with e.g. `[1]`: no, that is indeed not a good idea and leads to brittle path expressions that fail easily if the document changes slightly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try

```
response.xpath("(//div[@class='news_li'])[0]").xpath("//div[@class='a1']").extract()
```

Use the [0] directly in the XPath.

Comment: It is very likely that this does not make a difference, and does not address the cause of the problem outlined by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that when combining XPath expressions like so:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='news_li']")[0].xpath("//div[@class='a1']").extract()
```

if the second expression starts with a double slash `//`, then elements are selected *anywhere in the document*, regardless of what was selected before. Put another way: even if the first expression:

```
//div[@class='news_li']
```

selects only `div` elements with a certain class attribute, the next one:

```
//div[@class='a1']
```

selects *all* `div` elements where `@class='a1'` in the entire document. That seems to be your problem.

**Solution: Use a relative path**

One possible solution is to use a *relative* path expression that does not start with `//`:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='news_li']")[0].xpath(".//div[@class='a1']").extract()
```

**General remarks**

Depending on the structure of your actual documents and if you can make certain assumptions, better solutions may be possible.

Also, in general, to process results "one at a time", you should

- write an XPath expression that selects all of those desired elements and return them as a list
- process each item in this list individually, for example with Python code

Comment: Thanks! your suggestion totally make sense. But i have come across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778086/scrapy-processing-items-with-pipeline/56897101?noredirect=1#comment100340174_56897101). In the original post. I noticed that he used '//' to select all ul tag with class 'artist-list' and all h2 tag with class 'title'. Isn't it true that '//' will select all the elements in the document?

And he also use a for loop to loop through all the parent div. But his result looks correct without multiplicative information, how did he do it?

Comment: @SamMinWong Yes, it is very likely that in this post `//` also selects all elements. But the accepted answer there also suggests something different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39778588/1987598. The results of the question itself do not look correct. Did my answer solve your problem?